# How to handle large (2GB<) files in WinMerge

Tags: 64-bit, winmerge

If I try to compare two files that are larger than 2GB in WinMerge, I get an error: Cannot open file  UniMemFile cannot handle files over 2 gigabytes. As far as I know this is related to the fact that WinMerge runs as a 32-bit process by default even if my computer is running a 64-bit Windows 7.

How can I configure WinMerge to run as a 64-bit process?

Comment: "How can I configure WinMerge to run as a 64-bit process?" - You would have to recompile the application.  It does not appear that will be easy, if the source code was 64-bit compatible, they would distribute 64-bit versions of Winmerge already compiled.  Even if you were to recompile it to be a 64-bit executable, more work goes into loading larger files, then just having a 64-bit executable. What you want isn't possible with substantial amount of work

Comment: I suggest using something other then WinMerge.  The last version was released 5 years ago.